# Share Internet connection to two networks

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, routing

I have a computer with two Ethernet ports and a Wireless adapter.

How do I share its Internet connection (connected to one Ethernet port) to both the Ethernet LAN and via Wi-Fi? I don't want to use a router.

For some reason the Wi-Fi interface doesn't have "Bridge" in its right-click menu. Perhaps I could set up NAT using the `netsh` and `route` commands?

Comment: I would strongly advise you to just spend to $30 to get a wireless router. Desktops make lousy routers when they're also being used as desktops. (Also, the answer depends on *precisely* what that Ethernet port is connected to. For example, is it a router? A modem with a built-in router? A modem without a built-in router that is just bridging?)

Comment: It's more of a server/workstation computer, so it's always-on.

Comment: What does that Ethernet port connect to?

Comment: The home LAN connection goes to a gigabit switch. The Internet goes directly to the ISP's router.

Comment: I'm really more interested if it's possible to do in software (Windows 7). I *think* it's possible e.g. by bridging the local interfaces then NAT-ing that, or by manually setting up routing tables. Maybe that's outside the scope of this SE site.

Comment: Yes, then bridging should work. No NAT should be needed, since presumably the switch has a router connected to it that's already doing NAT. (Though it's hard to be sure because we don't have enough details about the setup.)

Comment: The switch is allocating me a global IP, so NAT is required.

Comment: Then you *definitely* want to get a cheap router to interpose between this machine and the switch. Performance will be very mediocre if you don't.

Comment: Why do you think performance will be poor? If I use a 100Mbit router for the home LAN, I'll lose the Gbit LAN speed. I suppose I could connect a Wi-Fi router to the switch instead, though.

Comment: Because PCs make lousy routers unless they're only being used as routers. The OS has many layers of overhead and takes a huge penalty when the CPU is interrupted.

Comment: I'd like to learn more about that topic. Do you have any sources with more information?

Comment: Gigabit routers start at $150 around here. A router can only decrease the workstation's Internet connection performance... Although I could imagine how a PC would need to do lots of work to route a packet, I think the router solution doesn't apply to my situation (Internet performance of other machines isn't as important anyway).

Comment: More like [$50](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124419). But I get your point about the workstation's performance being more important. You can use [ICS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing).

Comment: The Wi-Fi interface doesn't have "Bridge" in its right-click menu... I guess that's due to the proprietary software that lets the adapter be an access point. I guess that means I can't use ICS. I'll continue my research regarding `netsh`...

Comment: ICS is an alternative to bridging. You *can't* bridge. You have to use ICS.

Comment: But then I can only select one interface in the "Home networking connection" dropdown?

Comment: Yeah, it's getting really ugly. You might be able to get `netsh` to do it.

Comment: ICS is not (very) configurable via `netsh`, and Routing and Remote Access is not configurable at all (the `routing` section in `netsh` is absent on non-server editions of Windows). I found a free program (Connectify Hotspot) which worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that [Connectify Hotspot](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/) was able to set up a NAT-ed Wi-Fi hotspot without changing the Internet Connection Sharing setting.

I'll update this answer after I try to connect the Ethernet LAN as well.

Edit: it worked.